# What is the meaning of this sentence? Is it normal to say this or is he scolding me?

Tags: meaning

I wrote in one of the social platform that

> " It's dangerous to talk to strangers, but it's perfectly okay to
>   marry one."

(In my country our parents search for a boy  , in some places girls see the boy in the marriage itself as their parents decision is the  final ).  So a guy commented that

> "Isn't this point a bit overrated these days?"

What does that mean ? . I just saw his comment  and didn't reply back. I don't know what to comment back ... please help me.what should I comment?

Comment: Are you sure you quoted him correctly? Sounds like he was scolding you -- and he sounds like a jerk. The world is full of people like this -- sometimes people just say things because they're grouchy. I don't think what you said is bad, and I wouldn't feel bad about it. :-)

Comment: What parts of the sentence don't you understand? If you look up the meanings of the individual words, that should explain what it means as a complete sentence.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question whether your original post was humorous, sarcastic, or intended to be taken at face value. Did you add the explanation you provided here in the original post? This kind of context may help understand what the response meant. Maybe the person is scolding you, maybe he misunderstood your intent, maybe he is just trying to sound smart and doesn't expect any response.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is a rather clever saying in the context of the culture you live in, but who knows what meaning your comment might convey to someone who lives in a different culture. The straight-forward meaning of the question is "Isn't this an exaggeration nowadays."

Whether asking such a question is rude is itself a matter of culture. In my culture, asking a question without demeaning the person questioned is not considered rude in most circumstances. The issue here seems to about culture, not language.

Comment: He belongs to same religion as mine.He knows our culture very well.

Comment: @ Annie Well, religion is not the same as culture. Ireland and Italy are both Catholic in religion, but have quite different cultures. In any case, the meaning of the question is "did you not exaggerate somewhat in terms of modern conditions." Whether it is rude in your culture to question what is a criticism of your culture is not a matter of linguistics. (By the way, I am not questioning your criticism of your culture's barbaric custom of marrying two people who have not even met each other, a custom potentially cruel to both bride and groom. And I thought your criticism was aptly phrased.)